# 2-variable function optimization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a easy optimization (max) problem with function $f(x,y) = xy$ with the constrain that $g(x,y)\to100x+50y=760$. I get the max with Lagrange at $f(\frac{19}{5},\frac{38}{5})=\frac{722}{25}$. The problem is, that $x$ must be an integer. How do I modify the Lagrange to solve this problem with this condition?

Answer (score 1):

Your optimization is correct for real values of $ \ x \ $ .  If you are restricted to using an integer value for $ \ x \ , $ you will need to compare the result for $ \ f(x,y) \ $ using the closest integer, $ \ x \ = \ 4 \ . $  Under the constraint, this would be

$$ \ (x, y) \ = \ (4, \frac{36}{5}) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(4, \frac{36}{5}) \ = \ \frac{144}{5} \ = \ 28.8 \  \ .  $$

This is still pretty close to the maximum for the function, which you found, $ \ \frac{722}{25} \ = \ 28.88 \ . $

[It will not be possible to match the relation $ \ y \ = \ 2x \ $ from the Lagrange equation, but the constraint is still met.  Because the constraint equation is $ \ 2x + y \ = \ 15.2 \ , $ it will also not be possible to make both variables integral.]

Answer (score 0):

That will be easy. Let your new g to be g(x,y) = 500x + 250y = 3800 then your new answer would be x = 19, and y = 38. And these are both integers. I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the problem statement does not require _both_ variable values to be integers.  (Also, rescaling the constraint equation as you did does not produce those values...)